# what this code do in c#

Tags: c#

```
if (!condition)
                    return objecttoreturn;
                {
              //some other code here
                }
```

Comment: It has non-matching braces. `(!condition))`.

Comment: Does nothing: it won't compile because you have an extra `)`

Comment: sorry i forget to remove the extra brace. now check it.

Comment: It gives steven spielberg the passes for The Adventures of Tintin: Secret of the Unicorn. Sorry, couldn't resist. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code will return `objecttoreturn` if the condition is not true

The code inside the brackets `{}` will be invoked otherwise. The brackets do not add any value except that any variables declared inside them cannot be used in the rest of the method.

Comment: He edited the code and I removed that part from the answer after that :)

Answer (score 2):

This code is equal to:

```
if (!condition)
{
     return objecttoreturn;
}
else
{
 //some other code here
}
```

There is no need for the else because it will not reach it there except if (!condition) not satisfied. And braces are just for informing there is another scope to run, also usable to collapse it (which can also be done by region).

Comment: It's not quite identical to your example - the stand-alone braces introduce scope inside the function, which is a subtle but important difference.

Comment: @slugster, `else {}` introduce scope inside the function, what's difference between these scopes?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I guess I need some serious sleep. changed to +1.

Comment: @ Martinho Fernandes, no matter and I removed my comments :)

Answer (score 1):

in other words

```
public object method() {

if(condition == false) 
  return objectToReturn;

{

//Block of code, developer can create a block to enclose some code to be more readable or to create block declaration of fields 

var a = "Field";

}

// the a is not available here

return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be correctly written as

```
if (!condition)
    return objecttoreturn;
//some other code here
```

If the value of condition is `true` then `objecttoreturn` is returned otherwise some other code is executed